# Blackberry screen navigation

Tags: blackberry

I want to know how to go from one screen to another by clicking a button that I have added to a  MainScreen.  I mean just like we do in the Android onClick event for a button - start  another startActivity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the event handler for the button click, just "push" the screen that you want to appear next, and it will be pushed to the top of the screen stack.  For example:

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(nextScreen);
```

Comment: can you give me Good BlackBerry Delevoping tutorials for beginners.

Comment: A good place to start is the BlackBerry Developer Zone: http://us.blackberry.com/developers/

Answer (score 0):

This will be better, using FieldChangeListener

```
button.setChangeListener(new FieldChangeListener()
{
    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) 
          {
           UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NextScreen());
          }
});
```

This is the alternative way than using,

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication.involeLater()
{};
```

Comment: The answer by marc will be comfortable only to a good developer, for a beginner, it will give more doubts, right. As I had many doubts while using marc's code. I didn't know where to use it.